# Rails: use REJECT_IF only on CREATE action for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

So I have many polymorphic children for a Profile object.  The models are designed to destroy after_save if the specific Object's field is blank.

But for accept_nested_attributes I don't want to create the child object in the first place if it's blank.  But if I leave the reject_if statement then the user no longer has the ability to empty the field on UPDATE because the reject_if rejects their blank input.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials, reject_if: proc { |att| att['username'].blank? }
accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, reject_if: proc {|att| att['number'].blank? }
accepts_nested_attributes_for :websites, reject_if: proc {|att| att['url'].blank? }
```

So I want to `reject_if: { ... }, on: :create`.  But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `on: :create` is used in combination with `validates`. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` doesn't have that option. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a method and instead of sending a proc into the `reject_if` option, which is the same, it is just more readable, so the code would look like:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials, reject_if: :social_rejectable?

private

 def social_rejectable?(att)
  att['username'].blank? && new_record?
 end
```

You can just repeat the methods and then clean it up with some metaprogramming or add the `new_record?` method on the `proc`

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials, reject_if: proc { |att| att['username'].blank? && new_record?}
```

Comment: undefined method `new_record?' for #<ActionController::Parameters

Comment: Try without the proc, instead use the full method in this case the `social_rejectable?(att)` it is working for me

Comment: Not working in Rails 5, despite docs says than new_record? is valid

Comment: ... the problem is when nested model have a file field, then it receives a blank parameter but the file "exist", is like the field should be populated but it isn't

Comment: the file fields won't be populated due to security reasons, maybe a hidden field can be an answer