# Rails: discard child record before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to discard an associated record before its parent is saved in a Rails callback if a condition is met. Doing a `throw :abort` doesn't stop the record from saving. Am I doing something wrong?

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :frames, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :frame_variables, through: :frames, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :frames, allow_destroy: true
end

class Frame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
  has_many :frame_variables
end

class FrameVariable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :frame
  
  attr_accessor :_delete

  before_save :discard_if_cleared

  def discard_if_cleared
    throw :abort if _delete == true
  end
end
```

```
def create
  @document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
  if @document.save
    redirect_to documents_path
  else
    redirect_to new_document_path(template: @document.template), flash: { error: "The document you tried to create was invalid: #{@document.errors.full_messages}" }
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: does abort work if you don't add the if _delete condition? Just wondering if the attr is not being set as you expect?

Comment: Oh, great intuition. It causes the whole process to fail, so my condition isn't being set, but that's not the desired result. I want the parent to save, just without an instance of this class as an association.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code on how both models are setup? It might be possible to conditionally build the association form the controller instead of trying to delete it during callback

Comment: They're each quite complicated classes, I've included the relations though to try to convey the setup.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to build Frame and FrameVariable along with the Document when params come in for the document in the controller?   Can you also please post that create action as well?

Comment: Added, the params are elsewhere though. Likewise the frames and variables are initialized in a different class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly have two options here:

1. To use a combination of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `:reject_if` block to not save the association conditionally by checking the `_delete` in the `:reject_if` block.

Catch there is in your current setup your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is on Document and not on Frame. If that can be changed this might work out.

2. To not build the Document object in one shot using nested attributes. Instead "open" up your parametes in the `create` action.  The build the `Frame` and it's relevant children based on `_delete` for the `FrameVariable`. and the "attach" the final `Frame` to the Document as usual using `build`

Sorry for a vague answer, but not understanding the full context of your models and what you can modify, these are the general approaches I can think of.

Finally doing it in `before_save` is def a bad idea because when you are building out the full model using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` rails will use a commit block and revert everything if something in the chain rejects it.

This blog goes in some details about using `:reject_if`

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes

Here's another example of using the reject block:

[Rails: use REJECT_IF only on CREATE action for nested attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660424/rails-use-reject-if-only-on-create-action-for-nested-attributes)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Including the entire classes if out of scope for the question I feel, but this is more than enough to proceed on. Thanks so much!

Comment: anytime! and good luck!

Comment: It turns out I don't even need `reject_if` if I call the attribute `_destroy` and have `allow_destroy: true` set!